# How can I shutdown an Apache Edgent background task?

Tags: iot, apache-edgent

Asume the following code snippet:

```
TStream<Integer> stream = top.generate(() -> {            
  try{
    Thread.sleep(1500);
  }catch(InterruptedException ex){
    //DO NOTHING
  }
  return (int)(Math.random() * 100);
});

TWindow<Integer, Integer> window = stream.last(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, zero());

TStream<Double> average = window.batch((values, key) -> {
  int sum = values.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
  return (double)sum / values.size();
});

average.peek(average1 -> LOGGER.info("Calculated average : " + average1));
job = dp.submit(top);
```

After calling `job = dp.submit(top)`, the threads executing the topology will continu to run in the background until the JVM is stopped.

How can I stop this background process programmatically? This is specifically usefull when an Edgent topology is running as a separate process with other tasks in the same JVM. I tried to call `job.cancel(true)`, but this does not solve the problem. The task keeps on running...

Answer (score 1):

Try closing the job via `Job.stateChange(Job.Action.CLOSE)`

See a sample use here:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-edgent-samples/blob/develop/topology/src/main/java/org/apache/edgent/samples/topology/JobExecution.java